# C semaphores using sem_wait()

Tags: c, semaphore

I am working with semaphores and I am struggling with one part of code.
**CODE:**

```
// semaphore initialized to zero
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    fork();
    // statements
    sem_wait(semaphore);
    printf("Process %d is done\n", i);
    exit(0);
}

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    sem_post(semaphore);
}
```

Problem is, that loop stops after first iteration because of `sem_wait`, but i would like it to stop only that current process, so all other iterations can be done and at the end of code, i will 'release' all processes. Is there a way how to accomplish this?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

```
// initialization of semaphore
semaphore = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
sem_init(semaphore, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Show us, how did you initialized `semarophe` variable.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "current process"? Once you explain what you mean by that, just wrap the call to `sem_wait` in an `if` statement that tests whatever it is you need to test.

Comment: Well, in for loop i call `fork()` N times, so i create N processes. So current process i mean each process every iteration.

Comment: @SevO I don't follow. If the current process is each process every iteration, then what isn't the current process?

Comment: Let's say `i=0` and first process is called. Code comes to part where semaphore is blocked. I want to accomplish that even process is blocked, loop continues, so one by one i create queue of processes and at the end i use `sem_post()` and release them.

Comment: So what is the criterion for whether a process should block or not?

Comment: Point is it should block all every process, problem is it doesn't block only process it block everything that follows, i.e. whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check fork return value. On that basis, you will be sure if code is executed under child or parent process. Accordingly call sem_wait.